# Oracle: error while trying to use formulas

Tags: oracle, oracle-apps

I created an element with an input value of type "Day" , when i write a formula i get this error.

Any idea what's wrong?

> APP-FF-33232:
>   EATC_EXTRA_DAYS_ENTRY_EFFECTIVE_DATE_ENTRY_VALUE has null or not found allowed, but no
>   default set specified.
>
> Cause:        If a Database Item has
>   null allowed, or not found allowed,
>   then the item must also specify a
>   default set to be used to provide
>   default values in the event of these
>   occurring.  The item named has one of
>   these conditions allowed, but the
>   default set column in the
>   FF_DATABASE_ITEMS table is null.
>
> Action:        Please refer to your
>   local support representative.

-

Comment: That's not an Oracle error, which uses functions & procedures... What are you actually developing with, so the tags can be updated to correctly reflect your issue?

Comment: I suspect that's the Oracle E-business suite (nee Oracle Applications) -- the OP needs to contact Oracle Support.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in Oracle Apps (to say the least) but the error message is fairly clear.  You - or someone - have written a Fast Formula which references a database column EATC_EXTRA_DAYS_ENTRY_EFFECTIVE_DATE_ENTRY_VALUE.  Apparently this column can be nullable, in which case your Formula needs to provide a default value.  Something like:

```
default for EATC_EXTRA_DAYS_ENTRY_EFFECTIVE_DATE_ENTRY_VALUE is 01-JAN-2010
```

Or perhaps you can use `SYSDATE` or `CURRENT_DATE` rather than a fixed value.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to error: You called database item in Fast formula,

you need to initialize the date to specific date

alias EATC_EXTRA_DAYS_ENTRY_EFFECTIVE_DATE_ENTRY_VALUE as day

default for day is 01-jan-2010